# How to zoom/move camera to display a polygon in Cesium.js (fit viewport to polygon bounds)

Tags: javascript, camera, cesiumjs

Ok, maybe I'm blind because clearly this is not advanced functionality.. but I'm looking at the [Camera docs for Cesium.js](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Camera.html), and I can't seem to find how you simply zoom/move the view to show a polygon?

I can position the camera to show the poly using the mean lat/lon values, like:

```
viewer.camera.setView({
    position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(lonMean, latMean, 45000.0)
});
```

But that's rubbish; I don't get the zoom...**I want the zoom/viewport to be adjusted to fit the polygon.**

Can anybody point out what I must be overlooking...

Comment: Never worked with Cesium but I suppose you have tried `zoomIn` and `zoomOut` methods mentioned in the [docs](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Camera.html) right?

Comment: Yeah, those functions just zoom in/out an arbitrary amount, no relation to my polygon bounds. Only related functions I've seen set the view by a rectangle or by xy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a polygon defined in the Entity API, then you can simply call `viewer.zoomTo(entity)` or `viewer.flyTo(entity)`. This works with any type of entity visualization, not just polygons, and is discussed in Cesium's [Creating Entities tutorial](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs-learn/cesiumjs-creating-entities/#camera-controls).

Comment: Perfect! Although I feel that the docs *are* a little vague on this.. look at the `flyTo()` function, no reference to accepting an Entity param : / http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Camera.html#flyTo

Comment: That's because the Camera.flyTo function does not accept an entity param.  This function is on the Viewer only, which is a higher level object.  The low-level Camera doesn't know anything about entities.  Obviously our doc has tons of room for improvement, I just wanted to clarify that for you.

Comment: Oops, yeah that's completely my oversight; not the docs - thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Sandcastle Camera Demo](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Camera.html&label=Showcases).  Pull-down the "Camera options" drop box, and select either "Fly to Rectangle" or "View a rectangle."  The camera will fly or snap to the rectangle, and the code editor shows how this is done.  Take a look through the other Sandcastle demos too, they contain lots of sample code for common actions in Cesium.

Here's the FlyTo code:

```
var west = -90.0;
var south = 38.0;
var east = -87.0;
var north = 40.0;
var rectangle = Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(west, south, east, north);

viewer.camera.flyTo({
    destination : rectangle
});
```

Comment: Sorry, interested in a Polygon - not a rectangle.

Comment: Yes, it's like `mapbox.fitBounds`. Solid.